# ogr2ogr giving "ERROR 1: Failed connect to 192.168.4.18:8181; Operation timed out" error?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

This is my command, which was working OK yesterday:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" ../geojson/myfile.geojson ../data/gml/myfile.gml 
  -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

The output is this:

```
ERROR 1: Failed connect to 192.168.4.18:8181; Operation timed out
```

I'm baffled, why would ogr2ogr need to connect anywhere?

Comment: GML schema check?

Comment: But then why would it be connecting to somewhere on the local network? And, how can I fix this?

Comment: No idea just stabbing in the dark at this point. Never seen it do that before.

Comment: 7 years later and my copy of ogr2ogr giving `ERROR 1: Failed to connect to 192.168.4.19` which is not a network that I've configured. I've search the source code for the text string, but see nothing.  The command does eventually work, but delays everything until it timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ogr2ogr is doing this on a `.gml` to `.geojson` conversion.

I was baffled too (see comment a while back).

I've just worked out where the IP address is coming from.  It seems ogr2ogr is trying to load the `.xsd` file specified in the `.gml` header.

[image]

As I said before, the process does complete successfully after a timeout.  Alternatively, you could clean the input files prior to processing.

Comment: I was having this issue too. Seems to be ok though. Thanks for digging!