# How can I debug hanging `ogr2ogr`?

Tags: ogr2ogr

I downloaded one of files from https://use-land-property-data.service.gov.uk/datasets/inspire/download and I am trying to convert it to some friendlier format with `ogr2ogr`

I tried `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gml` but `ogr2ogr` just sits there frozen.

How can I enable some verbose debug (I already figured out that `.xml` file downloaded from this website is actually a `.zip` archive)

In this case problem turned out to be [ogr2ogr giving "ERROR 1: Failed connect to 192.168.4.18:8181; Operation timed out" error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90004/ogr2ogr-giving-error-1-failed-connect-to-192-168-4-188181-operation-timed-ou) - still some way to make `ogr2ogr` more verbose for future uses would be welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.google.com/search?q=ogr2ogr+enable+debug+output send me to https://gdal.org/programs/vector_common_options.html which suggests:

```
--debug <value>
```

and says

> Control what debugging messages are emitted. A value of ON will enable all debug messages. A value of OFF will disable all debug
> messages. Otherwise, a debug messege will be emitted if its category
> appears somewhere in the value string.

So try `ogr2ogr --debug ON -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gml`.

For more information if remote services might be involved (GML is such a format, there are namespaces and whatnot that might make GDAL make network calls to remove servers) you can add `--config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES` (thanks @user30184 for the hint).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue with those datasets. I downloaded the one for Liverpool and got a similar issue to you.
Having a poke inside the GML file, I found this line:

`<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:LR="www.landregistry.gov.uk" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="156026" numberReturned="156026" timeStamp="2022-10-02T02:51:49.265Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://192.168.4.19:5080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd www.landregistry.gov.uk http://192.168.4.19:5080/geoserver/LR/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=2.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=LR%3APREDEFINED http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://192.168.4.19:5080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">`

The upshot of this is that His Majesty's Land Registry has hard-coded the URLs for the schemas to point to their own internal servers! The first thing would be to let them know they've made a bit of a booboo. The next thing is to add the `DOWNLOAD_SCHEMA=NO` output option:

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -oo DOWNLOAD_SCHEMA=NO foo.shp Land_Registry_Cadastral_Parcels.gml`